# Geting prompt values from another query through functions

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I am a beginner in cognos 10. I want to know how to get the value of a prompt from a Query1 and use it on Query2. My requirement is I want a prompt to ask the year for which I want the data in Query1 and in Query2 I want the data relevant to the previous year to that entered in the prompt. How to do that?

Comment: So query 1 will list what years to select for the prompt, then query 2 is filtered by the selection?  Or are both queries filtered by the same year? Parameter/Prompt Tutorial here: https://www.stthomas.edu/media/informationresourcestechnologies/pdf/Understanding_Parame.pdf

Comment: Please do not all-caps your question title. It makes it difficult to read amongst other things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same parameter (tied to the prompt) in filters in both queries. If your parameter is Parameter1 and contains a four-digit year, and your data item in your filter is [Year] then your Query1 filter might look like this:

```
[Year] = ?Parameter1?
```

Your Query2 filter would be:

```
[Year] = ?Parameter1? - 1
```

Depending on your data source you may have to cast the string parameter to an integer before doing the subtraction though most SQL implementations will implicitly convert the string parameter to an integer for you.